# 2 tabulars with supposed same size aren't actually the same size

Tags: tables

I am sorry if the header doesn't make too much sense, but I will try to describe the problem more thoroughly. I have the code shown below which gives me the tabulars also shown in the picture.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Qualität}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Wände}} & `enter code here`\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Oben/Unten}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Geschwin-\\digkeit}}}\\
    \hline
    Schichtdicke & Linienbreite & \makecell[tl]{Anzahl der\\ Wandlinien} & \makecell[tl]{ Oberfläche\\ Außenhaut\\ Linien-\\breite} & \makecell[tl]{Glätten \\ aktivieren} & \makecell[tl]{Druckge- \\schwindig- \\keit}\\
    \hline
    0.15mm & 0.2mm & 0 & 0.2mm & \checkmark & 25mm/s\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Material}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Druckplattenhaftung}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Sonder-\\funktionen}}}\\
    \hline
    \makecell[tl]{Drucktem- \\peratur} & Temperatur der Druckplatte & Fluss & \makecell[tl]{Haftungs-\\typ} & \makecell[tl]{Anzahl der\\ Skirtlinien} & \makecell[tl]{Druckreihen-\\folge}\\
    \hline
    $\mathrm{230^\circ C}$ & $\mathrm{70^\circ C}$ & 106\% & Skirt & 10 & Nacheinander \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
\label{tab:Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
```

\end{figure}

Although I have all the same sizes for the columns both in the top and the bottom tabular (p{2.0cm}) the tabulars still aren't the same size, they don't even align perfectly on the left. This is very weird to me and I have tried some ideas but the all don't work. Can someone help me with the problem? Thank you[image]

Comment: We need a minimal working example. We don't know what packages you are using.

Comment: your code produces errors due to markdown errors `\`enter code here\`\multicolumn` please post a complete small document that shows the problem

Comment: So long as \multicolumn is smaller than the replaced p columns, no problem.  It is the last column that excedes the 2cm limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you modify the column type to perform automatic centering of the cell contents and allow line-breaking of the first word in a cell. (The `p` column type does neither.) I further suggest you get rid of the `\makecell` wrappers, and I recommend that you employ the `siunitx` package and its `\qty` macro to typeset physical quantities and their associated units. Last but not least, do insert a line break *before* `\bigskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \checkmark macro
\usepackage{array}    % for \newcolumntype macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering macro
% column type that allows hyphenation of first word in a cell:
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage[,locale=DE,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % '\qty' macro
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\centering

\begin{tabular}{| *{6}{C{2.0cm}|} }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Qualität}} &
\textbf{Wände} & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Oben\slash Unten}} & 
\textbf{Geschwindigkeit} \\
\hline
Schichtdicke & 
Linienbreite & 
Anzahl der Wandlinien & 
Oberfläche Außenhaut Linienbreite & 
Glätten aktivieren & 
Druck\-geschwin\-digkeit \\ % optional: indicate preferred line break points
\hline
\qty{0.15}{\milli\meter} & 
\qty{0.2}{\milli\meter} & 0 & 
\qty{0.2}{\milli\meter} & 
\checkmark & 
\qty{25}{\milli\meter\per\second} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % insert line break *before* this command
\begin{tabular}{| *{6}{C{2.0cm}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Material}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Druckplattenhaftung}} & 
\textbf{Sonderfunktionen} \\
\hline
Druck\-temperatur & 
Temperatur der Druckplatte & 
Fluss & Haftungstyp & 
Anzahl der Skirtlinien & 
Druck\-reihenfolge \\ % optional: indicate preferred line break points
\hline
\qty{230}{\celsius} & 
\qty{70}{\celsius} & 
106\% & 
Skirt & 
10 & 
Nacheinander \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
\label{tab:Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You did not provide an example, but one can be constructed as

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand\checkmark{?}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Qualität}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Wände}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Oben/Unten}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Geschwin-\\digkeit}}}\\
    \hline
    Schichtdicke & Linienbreite & \makecell[tl]{Anzahl der\\ Wandlinien} & \makecell[tl]{ Oberfläche\\ Außenhaut\\ Linien-\\breite} & \makecell[tl]{Glätten \\ aktivieren} & \makecell[tl]{Druckge- \\schwindig- \\keit}\\
    \hline
    0.15mm & 0.2mm & 0 & 0.2mm & \checkmark & 25mm/s\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Material}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Druckplattenhaftung}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Sonder-\\funktionen}}}\\
    \hline
    \makecell[tl]{Drucktem- \\peratur} & Temperatur der Druckplatte & Fluss & \makecell[tl]{Haftungs-\\typ} & \makecell[tl]{Anzahl der\\ Skirtlinien} & \makecell[tl]{Druckreihen-\\folge}\\
    \hline
    $\mathrm{230^\circ C}$ & $\mathrm{70^\circ C}$ & 106\% & Skirt & 10 & Nacheinander \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
\label{tab:Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note you need `12pt` document option.

The issue is caused  by

```
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\makecell{Sonder-\\funktionen}}}
```

which over-rides the `p` specification and says to use `c` so making a column as wide as the entry `funktionen` is wider than the column at 12pt. So you need to split that text differently, or re-adjust your `p` widths to give more space to that column.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that prescribed column width is a bit to small that texts in cells with normal font size can be nicely fit in them. Without knowing your document page layout is hard to see reasons why they have width of 2 cm. I would be expect that columns width in table with 6 columns will be defined by 1/6 of - unfortunately unknown - text width.

Better fit of text in cells can be achieved by use of smaller font size too. For example with `\small` size.

Considering aforementioned, I would select `tabularx` or `tblr` of `tabularray` package for table design, `\small` font size for text and similar as do @Mico in his answer, enable line-breaking of the first words in cells' texts and use `siunitx` for writing quantities.

MWE with `tblr` table can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}   % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\hyphenation{Druck-geschwin-digkeit Druck-reihen-folge}

\usepackage{amssymb}    % for \checkmark
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for \RaggedRight macro
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}% for \qty
\sisetup{locale=DE,
         per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { *{6}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]} },
             colsep  = {3pt},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, m}
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    Qualität
    &   &    Wände  
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Oben\slash Unten    
                &   &   Geschwindigkeit                     \\
Schichtdicke 
    &   Linienbreite 
        &   Anzahl der Wandlinien 
            &   Oberfläche Außenhaut Linienbreite 
                &   Glätten aktivieren 
                    &   Druckgeschwindigkeit                \\
\qty{0.15}{\milli\meter} 
    &   \qty{0.2}{\milli\meter} 
        & 0 &   \qty{0.2}{\milli\meter} 
                &   \checkmark 
                    &   \qty{25}{\milli\meter\per\second}   \\
\end{tblr}

\medskip
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { *{6}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]} },
             colsep  = {3pt},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, m}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    Material
    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Druckplattenhaftung
                &   &   Sonderfunktionen                        \\
Druck\-temperatur 
    &   Temperatur der Druckplatte 
        &   Fluss 
            &   Haftungstyp 
                &   Anzahl der Skirtlinien 
                    &   Druckreihenfolge                        \\
\qty{230}{\celsius} 
    &   \qty{70}{\celsius} 
        &   \qty{106}{\%}
            &   Skirt 
                &   10 
                    &   Nacheinander                            \\
\end{tblr}

\caption{Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
\label{tab:Druckereinstellungen der ersten Versuchsreihe}
    \end{figure}    
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]